# How do I stop a countertop soap dispenser from leaking?

Tags: kitchens, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures, soap-dispenser

I have a countertop soap dispenser.  It is a Blanco 911-375 Alta Soap/Lotion Dispenser, Satin Nickel Finish filled with Seventh Generation brand dish soap.  For the high-end-quality brand name, it shouldn't be producing external soap clumps like a piece of junk might.  Also, the white tube part (see the photos) does not maintain an attachment to the metal head; when I pull the pump head up, it disconnects from the white tube.

I am waiting to hear back from the manufacturer (Blanco) for advice, but aside from removing the soap and stopping using it, **what are my alternatives to prevent this thing from leaking soap?**  I have tried diluting the soap in the soap receptacle with water, but that didn't do much.

Photos of scenario (click each for larger):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yuk!  Have you tried a different type of soap?

Comment: Not yet; diluting it should have worked.  I'll wait to hear from the manufacturer on that front; wondering if there is an alternate cure than replacing the soap.

Comment: I contacted the manufacturer, and the resolution is cited below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the manufacturer, Blanco, via the contact page on their website.  They got back to me via e-mail the next day.  Apparently, the ribbed white tube is not connecting correctly to the metal pump top; they've had this problem before.  They sent me a whole new white interior tube part.

The new part fit nicely, staying with the metal pump top when pulled up instead of separating like the original piece did.  Unfortunately, it failed to pump any soap up, even after diluting the soap.

I e-mailed Blanco with the results, and a company representative called me the next day to coordinate a time when I could be at the sink.  It turned out that the ball bearing at the top of the white part they sent me had disengaged from the top (I later found it disguised on my speckled granite counter); the plastic tongs that had been holding it in place had broken away.  They sent me a second replacement part.

The second replacement part fit just like the first replacement, but this time I identified the ball bearing was held correctly in place.  The pump has worked perfectly without leaking ever since.  As this was well under a year since purchase, the parts were free under warranty.

**TL;DR: This issue was solved by contacting the company and replacing the white tube part.**

Answer (score 2):

So it appears to be leaking at the connection of the white plastic pump to the metal dispensing spout? The first issue to check is to make sure the liquid soap has not congealed inside the metal spout. Soak it in hot water and then gently probe the opening with a soft blunt object to break away any mineral or crust deposits. Next, reconnect the white pump to the spout. Make sure it is fully seated and securely in place. If it can be removed easily by hand it won't dispense and leak soap. Before you try to use it for liquid soap fill a container  large enough to submerse the spout and pump under warm water. Work the pump slowly a few times. After 3-4 pumps you should see water jetting from the spout end. Position the spout above the water line while keeping the pump pick-up (suction) end submersed. Pumping should now produce copious squirts of water from only the spout end. Place the unit back into place while leaving any water inside the pump. Push the knob until soap appears with no leakage.

Comment: I tried your suggestions before contacting the manufacturer, but it didn't solve the issue, which was an actual bad part.  Having a replacement part supplied to me solved the issue.